# NSData writeToFile method returns true but file is not written to the disk

Tags: swift, macos, nsdata, osx-yosemite, writetofile

I have developed an OS X app and I sometimes need to save some pictures to the disk. I have a method to do that :

```
func saveImageAtPath(image: NSImage, path: String)
{
    if let data = image.TIFFRepresentation
    {
        let bitmap = NSBitmapImageRep(data: data)
        let pngImage = bitmap?.representationUsingType(NSBitmapImageFileType.NSPNGFileType, properties: [:])
        
        NSLog("Path : %@", path)
        
        if let _ = pngImage?.writeToFile(path, atomically: false)
        {
            NSLog("Everything should work...")
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to save an image, everything seems to work, the following text is displayed in the console :

> Path :
> /Users/myusername/Documents/Pictures/Apps/testPictures/mypicture.png
>
> Everything should work...

Everything was working perfectly a month ago.
Here is my conf :

OS X Yosemite 10.10.5
Xcode 7.2

If anyone has an idea... That'd be great !

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `if let _ = pngImage?` unwraps the optional but does not consider the `Bool` result of `writeToFile`. Use `writeToFile:options:error:` to catch the error

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I should have thought about that ... `writeToFile:options:error` doesn't seem to exist anymore. And I can't succeed in catching the error using `writeToFile(path: String, options: NSDataWritingOptions) throws`

Comment: You have to wrap the `throws` method in a `do - try <method> - catch` block

Comment: Thanks for your quick answers vadian. The thing I don't understand is that I can't really catch the error, I have to create my custom errors, right ? So how am I supposed to know what happened exactly ?

Comment: No, a method which `throws` does throw an error. All methods including an error pointer (**NSError) appear as `throw` methods in Swift 2. Please read the chapter about error handling the in Swift Language Guide.

Comment: Thanks again ! I finally catched the error "You don’t have permission to save the file “...” in the folder "..." ", I'll check that so :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I spent all day trying to figure out how to code up the suggested fix in swift 2.0 , so I wanted to share now that I have it working

```
do{
    let result = try Bool(pngImage!.writeToFile(filePath, options: NSDataWritingOptions.DataWritingAtomic))
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

I hope that saves someone some time.